# Is the canonical map from isometry group of a Gromov hyperbolic space to homeomorphisms of its Gromov boundary injective?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose X is a proper Gromov hyperbolic space and $\partial X$ is its Gromov boundary. It is well-known that there is a canonical group homomorphism  $\Phi$ from the isometry group of X to the group of homeomorphisms of $\partial X$.

My question is whether this map $\Phi$ is injective.

What about if we do not assume X is proper? Will the map $\Phi$ be injective?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Consider $X$ which is bounded... How about $X={\mathbb R}$? What answer do you get in these examples?

Comment: Unless the boundary is a aingleton: if $X$ is proper, the kernel is the "compact radical", i.e., largest compact normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Isom}(X)$ (which exists in this case). In the non-proper case one can still define an obvious natural notion of boundedness in $\mathrm{Isom}(X)$ and I think we get the largest normal bounded subgroup. The exception is when the boundary is a singleton and the action is unbounded. For instance, when $X$ is a horodisc in the hyperbolic plane. This exception can't occur when there are loxodromics / when the action is cobounded.

Comment: @YCor : You are saying that if we exclude the case when the boundary of $X$ is a singleton and the action is unbounded , then the map $\Phi$ is injective. Am I correct? This is both for proper and non-proper case, right? Could you explain the proof?  However, AGenevois provided a counter-example below in the case when the boundary has exactly two points !

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is the other counterexample. No need to add hair: just the graph $\mathbf{Z}$ is already one. I'll post an answer with details.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is indeed another counterexample.  No need to add hair: just the graph $\mathbf{Z}$ is already one. In the other direction, a bounded normal subgroup need not act trivially on the boundary (e.g., modify a bit the metric on the hyperbolic plane so that the isometry group is reduced to $\mathrm{SO}(2)$). I'll post an answer with details.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be the planar graph

- whose vertices are the points $(i,j)$ for $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $j \in \{-1,0,1\}$;
- whose edges connect $(i,0)$ with $(i+1,0)$ for every $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $(i,\pm 1)$ with $(i,0)$ for every $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

In other words, $X$ is a bi-infinite line with top and bottom neighbours added to every vertex.

Of course, $X$ is a locally finite hyperbolic graph (it's a tree). It is not difficult to verify that its isometry group is the unrestricted wreath product
$$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\ \mathrm{wr} \ \mathbb{D}_\infty = \left( \prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z} \right) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}.$$
Each $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ from the product corresponds to an isometry that swaps the top and bottom neighbours $(i,1)$ and $(i,-1)$ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ but fixes all the other vertices. The $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to the obvious translation. And the right $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ corresponds to a left-right reflection.

The boundary $\partial X$ of $X$ contains only two points, and the action of $\mathrm{Isom}(X)$ on $\partial X$ corresponds to the projection onto the right factor $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Consequently, the kernel of the action is the unrestricted wreath product
$$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \ \mathrm{wr} \ \mathbb{Z}:= \prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z},$$
which is uncountably infinite.

The key point is that hyperbolicity has no control on small scale geometry. By using the same trick of adding top and bottom neighbours, you can start from your favourite hyperbolic graph $Y$ and create a new hyperbolic graph $Y^+$ (quasi-isometric to $Y$) whose isometry group contains an uncountably infinite subgroup $\prod \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in the kernel of its action on $\partial Y^+$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be the isometry group of a quasi-geodesic Gromov-hyperbolic space $X$. If $X$ is empty there's not much so say, so assume otherwise. Say that $B\subset G$ is bounded if $Bx$ is bounded for some/every $x\in X$. When $X$ is proper, this just means that $B$ has compact closure.

Let $W$ be the kernel of the $G$-action on the Gromov boundary $\partial X$.

From Gromov's classification, an isometric action on a Gromov-hyperbolic falls into exactly one of the following (a) **bounded** orbits (b) **horocyclic**: unbounded, a unique fixed point on the boundary, no loxodromic (c) **axial**: a fixed pair on the boundary and some loxodromic, no other finite orbit on the boundary (d) **focal**: a unique fixed point on the boundary, some loxodromic (e) **general type** two loxodromic with disjoint ends.

We apply this to the $W$-action. (d), (e) are excluded since not all points can be fixed. (c) (axial) is possible only if the boundary is reduced to a pair (b) (horocyclic) is possible only if the boundary is a singleton. (a) is possible.

A) If the $G$-action is axial and the boundary is a pair, the $G$-action is axial as well. Let $E$ be a $G$-orbit: it is a quasi-geodesic. Suppose by contradiction that $E$ is not cobounded in $G$. Then since the $G$-action on $E$ is cobounded, for some $C$ and all $n$ there exists $x_n$ with $d(x_n,x_0)\le n$ and $d(x_n,E)\ge n-C$. Using hyperbolicity, one can show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is not equivalent to any one representing one of the ends of $E$. So there's a third point on the boundary, contradiction. Then $E$ is cobounded. In this case, the kernel $W$ is $G$ or has index 2 in $G$ according to whether $G$ switches the two boundary points.

Hence, if the $W$-action is axial, we are in (A) as above.

If the $W$-action is horocyclic, there's a single boundary point. Hence the $G$-action is horocyclic as well.

Otherwise the $W$-action is bounded, so $W$ is indeed bounded.

A bounded subgroup $H$ need not act trivially on the boundary. However, this holds if the $G$-action is cobounded and $H$ is normal in $G$.

---

In summary, we have exactly one of the following:

1. $W$ is bounded (and if $G$ acts coboundedly, it is the largest bounded normal subgroup)
2. $G$ acts horocyclically, and $\partial X$ is a singleton (example: $X$ horodisc in hyperbolic plane) — in this case $G$ can't act coboundedly
3. $G$ acts axially coboundedly on $X$ (so $X$ is quasi-isometric to $\mathbf{Z}$); $W$ has index 1 or 2 on $G$ according to whether $G$ fixes the two boundary points.

Comment: Thank you for yor answer! Could you elaborate a bit more why " (d), (e) are excluded " ? I have another question related to this statement. Suppose a subgroup $H$ of $Isom(X)$ is acting non-elementarily on $X$ ( I guess this is same as option (d) and (e) ). Is it true that the intersection of $W$ and $H$ is trivial  ?

Comment: In (d), (e), there's a loxodromic but a single global fixed point. So there are at least 3 boundary points. So the loxodromic moves one of them. Hence the action on the boundary is nontrivial.

Comment: For your second question, taking $H=\mathrm{Isom}(G)$, you're asking whether $W$ is trivial... no, just take a trivalent tree with 2 hair at each vertex.